# Dispatch Event doesn't work in IE and Firefox after last Windows update

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

This script used to work before, now it only works in Chrome, but not in IE and Firefox. What changed? Maybe last Windows patch?

```
function SetSel(value)
{
    switcher_combo.value = value;  
    switcher_combo.selected = true;
    //switcher_combo.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));

    var event = document.createEvent("Event");
    event.initEvent("change", false, true); 
    switcher_combo.dispatchEvent(event);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Both `createEvent` and `initEvent` are non-standard and deprecated, so I wouldn't be surprised if Firefox/IE have dropped it.

Comment: try this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event

Comment: This is what I commented out as it didn't work with IE. The old method worked everywhere until I upgraded my OS with latest patch. Unless I'm missing something....